# Serving Static Files with Common Lisp

Tags: http, webserver, common-lisp, static-files

I'm writing a minimal web server in Common Lisp, and want it to be able to have some basic static file serving ability. The idea is for this to be used in development, testing and other low-traffic situations, so it doesn't have to be particularly efficient. It also won't have to deal with large files. It does, however, have to work, and this errors when attempting to serve images:

```
...
(with-open-file (s path :direction :input :element-type 'octet)
             (let ((buf (make-array (file-length s) :element-type 'octet)))
               (read-sequence buf s)
               (write! (make-instance 
                'response :content-type mime
                :body buf) 
                   sock))
             (socket-close sock))
...
```

Specifically, it gives me the error

```
The value 137 is not of type CHARACTER.
   [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
...
```

The relevant part of `write!` looks like

```
...
(write-string "Content-Length: " stream) (write (length body) :stream stream) (crlf stream)
(crlf stream)
(write-sequence body stream)
(crlf stream)
...
```

I've tried changing it to

```
...
(write-string "Content-Length: " stream) (write (length body) :stream stream) (crlf stream)
(crlf stream)
(write-string (flexi-streams:octets-to-string body) stream)
(crlf stream)
...
```

whereupon the error disappears, but the client gets a mangled version of the file. You can see more context around the above code [here](https://github.com/Inaimathi/deal/blob/house-server-port/house/house.lisp#L207-L214).

What am I doing wrong?

The system is built on top of `:usocket` and uses `:flexi-streams` for `octet`. The above is taking a very similar approach to Hunchentoot (see the static file snippet [here](https://github.com/edicl/hunchentoot/blob/master/misc.lisp#L171-L186); that code does chunking and a few other checks before-hand, but otherwise seems to be doing the same thing I am above). I'm running the latest stuff out of `:quicklisp` for everything, and running it on `SBCL 1.0.57.0.debian` on top of 64-bit Debian stable.

Comment: Set the flexi-stream external format to the appropriate encoding. Probably utf-8.

Comment: @WhiteCat - Any hints on how to make a `socket-stream` into a `flexi-stream`? The naive `(flex:make-flexi-stream (socket-stream sock) :external-format :utf-8)` results in getting type errors when I try to write to the result (it reports that the stream is not a binary output stream). I also can't find the code that does this job in Hunchentoot (though it must at some point; a socket starts off with `usocket:socket-accept` in `acceptor.lisp`, and ends up being written to through `write-sequence` in `misc.lisp`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to `jasom` and `Bike` from `#lisp` for the answer:

If you want to serve static files from a `usocket`-based server, you need to

1. Include `flexi-streams`
2. Make sure to create binary streams when accepting
3. Make the streams bivalent before doing anything (otherwise character/string writes/reads are going to error on you)

The first point is easy enough. Either call `(ql:quickload :flexi-streams)`, or add `#:flexi-streams` to the `:depends-on` line of your `.asd`.

The second point involves calling `socket-accept` with the additional argument:

```
(socket-accept ready :element-type 'octet)
```

Third, instead of passing around a socket and writing to `(socket-stream socket)` everywhere, you'll need to do a `make-flexi-stream` call.

```
(let ((stream (flex:make-flexi-stream (socket-stream sock) :external-format :utf-8)))
    ;;; stuff you want to do
    )
```

Depending on your specific situation, it might make sense either to wrap every write/read in the above, or do it once (right after you call `socket-accept`) then pass the `flexi-stream` around along with the socket.