# Caveman2 How to serve a file dynamically?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, caveman2

I would like to be able to serve a file with [Caveman2.](https://github.com/fukamachi/caveman) The reason I want a way to return it from a controller and not make a static route available to anyone is to be able to only serve the file to authenticated users that have the permission level required.

I found this answer, including it here for reference: [Serving Static Files with Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320540/serving-static-files-with-common-lisp) , and while I found that my quicklisp had already included `usocket` and `flexi-streams`, I did not follow exactly how to do it. Which socket should I use? Is that the correct way of doing it? Is that what's supposed to be done from Caveman2

From here [How do I force files to open in the browser instead of downloading (PDF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-do-i-force-files-to-open-in-the-browser-instead-of-downloading-pdf) it seems that for the browser to handle the response correctly I need to set certain headers.

So this seems to be just a question of how to return a file to the browser.

Since this seems like such a standard operation I image there's a standard way of doing it and I don't want to reinvent the wheel over here, just couldn't find it in the docs...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to solve the problem was to return a sequence. First read the file into a sequence and then return it.

As included in the question, the correct headers need to be set.

1. `Content-Type` is set like this:
   `(setf (getf (caveman2:response-headers caveman2:*response*) :content-type) "image/png")`.
   This example has `"image/png"` but you can set it up depending on whatever the file is.
2. `Content-Disposition is set similarly

```
  (setf
   (getf (caveman2:response-headers caveman2:*response*) :content-disposition)
   "attachment; filename=\"filename.png\"")
```

You can replace `attachment` in the code above with `inline` and it will prompt for a file download instead of an in browser render.

Finally, and the main answer to the question, is to return a sequence of the byte-vector.

```
(alexandria:read-stream-content-into-byte-vector STREAM)
```

In my case, since I'm using mito-attachment, I'm including the code here for reference:

```
(alexandria:read-stream-content-into-byte-vector 
  (mito-attachment:get-object 
    (mito:find-dao 'class-name :file-key file-key)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be over-complicated things? Routes are expected to return a string. The default content type is "text/html", but you can return any string, it will display in the browser.

Here with another routing library (easy-routes, to adapt for Caveman syntax) I just read the file content and return it:

```lisp
(defroute test-readme-route ("/readme") ()
  (format nil "~a" (str:from-file "README.md"))) ;; see also uiop:read-file-string
```

I didn't set headers, see `(hunchentoot:headers-out*)` or clack-related functions.

Comment: Thanks, actually we can return any sequence, it doesn't have to be a string. I found this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76915301/convert-a-flexi-stream-containing-a-vector-of-octets-to-a-utf-8-string-in-common